# Prevent disabling wifi when connected using Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I am using a Dell Vostro N1550 Laptop with 1702 WLAN card and has internet connection over Ethernet

I need to share my internet connection with my mobile ( BlackBerry Q5)

When I created an Ad-hoc network, I was able to connect laptops but none of the mobiles are able to discover wifi

When I tried to use Connectify Client, the lan connection is automatically disabling the wifi

How should I disable this?

Comment: Disable what exactly the Connectify?

Comment: @50-3 I need to disable the action which is as follows "Disable Wifi on Ethernet Connection"